# List of tables in databse do not show in php maker

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using phpmaker 10 to load my database.When loading the database,list of tables do not show.Can anyone solve this problem?
Thank you.

[image: From the image below, the tables section doesn't show any list of tables.]

Comment: you should share your php code and description of table not just image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you need to check out on the steps in FAQ **Q.  Add/Edit/Delete/Update pages are not generated.** at http://www.hkvstore.com/phpmaker/faq.asp

It points out the need to ensure that you have a primary key for the table, synchronizing to update the project and regenerating scripts after adding primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

On top menu bar there is Refresh button before help menu. Try that once. If possible can you upload your db dump to diagnosis this issue locally.